# MS Office 2013 - App Crash after a few minutes

Tags: installation, microsoft-office-2013

When I try to run `MS Office ProPlus 2013` on `Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter`, I get the below error messageafter a few minutes of the app running, but with `powerpnt.exe` or `excel.exe` or `winword.exe`. I tried rebooting, starting in safe mode, and `sfc /fix`, but nothing works. I tried to reinstall, and I got the below message after a few minutes. I would like help to fix this problem.

```
Source
Microsoft Office

Summary
Stopped working

Date
‎2015-‎02-‎14 4:16 PM

Status
Not reported

Description
Faulting Application Path:  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\FIRSTRUN.EXE

Problem signature
Problem Event Name: BEX
Application Name:   firstrun.exe
Application Version:    15.0.4693.1000
Application Timestamp:  54b5d24d
Fault Module Name:  StackHash_cdb8
Fault Module Version:   0.0.0.0
Fault Module Timestamp: 00000000
Exception Offset:   PCH_2A_FROM_AppVIsvSubsystems32+0x0005ABEB
Exception Code: c0000005
Exception Data: 00000008
OS Version: 6.3.9600.2.0.0.400.8
Locale ID:  4105
Additional Information 1:   cdb8
Additional Information 2:   cdb81aa23bde0ee5f99eaa851c2afbd5
Additional Information 3:   7c9d
Additional Information 4:   7c9dd1c70fe6b2a0efb049136e4da130
```

Comment: `I tried rebooting, starting in safe mode, and sfc /fix` - Because when something doesn't work you should just randomly run sfc, gpupdate, and disable the Windows firewall.

Comment: @joeqwerty , i mean starting office in safe mode, and I ran sfc, because I was also having problems with some of my other apps, so I thought it might be some system files

Comment: if you run `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\FIRSTRUN.EXE` directly, do you get an immediate crash? This would be easier to debug. If so, the first thing I'd try is to rename that program (to `firstrun.exe.NOT`for example) and see if you can use Office apps without that. If not, we'll need to diagnose deeper.

Comment: Have you tried [office repair](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repair-an-Office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b?ui=en-US&rs=en-001&ad=US)?

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes, i have, but it crashes at the same error